# Result is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, math

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var result = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    if (document.getElementById('add')) {
        function myFunction() {
            add1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
            add2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
            ans = (parseInt(add1)+parseInt(add2));
            result.innerHTML = ans;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="num1" />
    <select id="problem">
        <option id="add">+</option>
        <option id="sub">-</option>
        <option id="mul">x</option>
        <option id="div">÷</option>
    </select>
<input type="text" id="num2" />
<br />
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction();" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="answer" readonly />
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make a sum solver by taking the values from the two text boxes and after clicking the button, it should post the result in the text box below. However it is not doing that.

I also want the program to change how a problem is solved using the dropdown menu with the mathematical symbols.

Thanks.

Comment: Math isn't as revelant as tags should be in this cinerio.

Comment: the function should be outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after something like this

```
function myFunction() {
    var result = document.getElementById('answer'),
        operator = document.getElementById('problem').value,
        add1 = document.getElementById('num1').value,
        add2 = document.getElementById('num2').value,
        ans = 0;

    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            ans = (parseInt(add1) + parseInt(add2));
            break;
        case '-':
            ans = (parseInt(add1) - parseInt(add2));
            break;
        case 'x':
            ans = (parseInt(add1) * parseInt(add2));
            break;
        case '÷':
            ans = (parseInt(add1) / parseInt(add2));
            break;
    }

    result.value = ans;
}
```

instead of using if statements, and creating different functions, just have one function and determine the operand.

**Edit:**   Also, watch out for your variable declarations. 'ans', 'add1' and 'add2' weren't being declared which resulted in global variables being created

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've never worked with switches and cases. I should definitely look into it!

Comment: @JamieVic glad I could help. Check out my update on `var` declarations too

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be with the line

```
var result = document.getElementById('answer').value;
```

Try the below snippet

```
var result=document.getElementById('answer');
ans = (parseInt(add1)+parseInt(add2));
result.value=ans;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2W5za/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.  Not sure what you were going for with the `if` but remove it.  Also, set the value of a textbox with `value` not `innerHTML`.

```
function myFunction() {
    var result = document.getElementById('answer');
    add1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    add2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
    ans = (parseInt(add1)+parseInt(add2));
    result.value = ans;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LjqMJ/

Comment: The `if` part of the code was to determine what specific problem the user had ie. addition, subtraction, multiplication, division.

Comment: You should mention to remove '.value' from the result variable.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of the question (and that for which this question is titled), one problem I see is this line of code right here:

```
var result = document.getElementById('answer').value;
```

What is the type of `result`?  Later on you treat it as if it is a `DOMElement` with `result.innerHTML = ans;` by assuming it has a property `innerHTML`.  However because you used `.value` it's in fact a `string` which will not have `innerHTML`.

Regarding the second part, you can assert which function is selected in the `<select>` by looking at it's `.value`.  The `<option>` tags will always exist, regardless of if they are selected or not.

Speaking more broadly, I highly recommend you check out using the debugger in either chrome or firefox.  That will allow you to drop a breakpoint in your code, and figure out if the value is being computed correctly, and see what it is attempting to write to, all interactively.

Chrome:
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code.  However, to fix your problem, change `= ans` to `= ans.toString();`

You see, in *javascript* **integers** and **strings** cannot change to each other's values without a conversion (kind of like a brother and sister refusing to share), so `toString()` is used for a conversion to `String`.

The other thing to change is `innerHTML` to `value`, because you are dealing with text boxes.

Comment: I don't want it to return a string

Comment: result.innerHTML has to be a string.  Also, use .value

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="num1" />
    <select id="problem">
        <option value="add">+</option>
        <option value="sub">-</option>
        <option value="mul">x</option>
        <option value="div">%</option>
    </select>
 <input type="text" id="num2" />
 <br />
 <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction();" />
 <br />
 <input type="text" id="answer" readonly />


 <script type="text/javascript">
     function myFunction() 
     {
         var e = document.getElementById("problem");
         var sOperation = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
         add1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
         add2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
         var ans;
         if (!isNaN(add1) && !isNaN(add2)){
        if(sOperation=='add'){
            //Add
            ans = parseInt(add1)+parseInt(add2);
        } else if (sOperation=='sub') {
            //Subtract
            ans = parseInt(add1)-parseInt(add2);
        } else if (sOperation=='mul') {
            //Multiple
            ans = parseInt(add1) * parseInt(add2);
        } else if (sOperation=='div') {
            //Divide
            ans = parseInt(add1) / parseInt(add2);
        }
        document.getElementById("answer").value = ans;      
    } else {
        alert("Please enter numeric values only");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="num1" />
<select id="problem">
    <option id="add">+</option>
    <option id="sub">-</option>
    <option id="mul">x</option>
    <option id="div">÷</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="num2" />
<br />
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction();" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="answer" readonly />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction() {
    var result = document.getElementById('answer');
    var operator = document.getElementById('problem').value;
    var add1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    var add2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
    var ans;
    if (!isNaN(add1) && !isNaN(add2)) {
        //Addition
        if (operator == '+')

        {

            ans = (parseInt(add1) + parseInt(add2));
        }
        //Subtraction
        else if (operator == '-') {

            ans = (parseInt(add1) - parseInt(add2));

        }
        //Multiplication
        else if (operator == 'x') {

            ans = (parseInt(add1) * parseInt(add2));

        }
        //Division
        else if (operator == '÷') {

            ans = (parseInt(add1) / parseInt(add2));
        }
        //Result
        result.value = ans;
    } else {
        alert("Please enter numeric values only");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M3Lkz/2/)**